# wxpython combobox prevent user from choosing other option once an option is selected

Tags: python

i would like to lock the combobox which prevent the user from choosing anything else once an start button was enter.

This is because i doing a monitoring process on an interface.The combobox have the list of interface name.Once i start the monitor , i do not want the user to choose other interface card until it was stop.

is there anyway to do it?

```
selectedInterface = self.interfaces_cblist.GetValue()
        self.selectInterfaceStr = str(selectedInterface)    
        if len(selectedInterface) == 0:
            noSelect_error = wx.MessageDialog(None,"Please select an interface","",wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
            noSelect_error.ShowModal()
        else:       
            monitorStarted = wx.MessageDialog(None,"Monitor on %s started"%self.selectInterfaceStr,"",wx.OK|wx.ICON_ERROR)
            monitorStarted.ShowModal()
            self.monitorInterface_button.Disable()
            self.abortValue = 1;
            self.camDetect = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.camtableDetection,args=(self.selectInterfaceStr,))
            self.dhcpDetect = multiprocessing.Process(target=self.dhcpexhaustion,args=(self.selectInterfaceStr,))
            self.camDetect.start()
            self.dhcpDetect.start()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to disable your combobox, you should be able to do something like:

```
self.interfaces_cblist.Enable(False)
```

(assuming interfaces_cblist is the combobox you want disabled...)